How to set HttpServletRequest headers when unit testing with GraphQlTester in kotlin?
I'm working on a Spring Boot project using Kotlin and GraphQL. For unit testing, I'm using GraphQlTester from org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester. I need to pass headers to the request, specifically "TENANT-CODE" and "SUB-TENANT-CODE". However, GraphQlTester does not seem to support to set headers directly.
Here is my test class:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureGraphQlTester
class CheckupUserTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val graphQlTester: GraphQlTester,
    private val checkupUserRepository: CheckupUserRepository,
) {
    
    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        val visibility = Visibility(
            clientCode = "....",
            tenantCodes = mutableListOf("X", "Y"),
            subTenantCodes = mutableListOf("XX", "YYY")
        )
        val checkupUser = CheckupUser(
            vendorAssignedRefId = "1111111111111111111111111111",
            gender = Gender.FEMALE,
            birthday = LocalDate.of(1996, 6, 26),
            additionalInfo = mutableMapOf("key" to "value"),
            visibility = visibility
        )
        checkupUserRepository.save(checkupUser)
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun tearDown() {
        checkupUserRepository.deleteAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldReturnCheckupUserAndSuccessStatusCodeWhenUsingValidFilter() {
        val result = graphQlTester.documentName("checkupUser/filter-checkup-user")
            .variable("page", 1)
            .variable("size", 2)
            .variable("filter", "(like,STRING,refId,)")
            .variable("sortBy", null)
            .execute()
            .path("filterCheckupUser.status")
            .entity(String::class.java).isEqualTo("S0000")
            .path("filterCheckupUser.totalElements")
            .entity(Int::class.java).isEqualTo(2)
            .path("filterCheckupUser.payload[1].vendorAssignedRefId")
            .entity(String::class.java).isEqualTo("...................")
            .path("filterCheckupUser.payload[0].gender")
            .entity(String::class.java).isEqualTo("MALE")
    }
}

In my controller, I need to get headers from HttpServletRequest like this:
private val request: HttpServletRequest

val tenantCode = request.getHeader("TENANT-CODE")
val subTenantCode = request.getHeader("SUB-TENANT-CODE")

How can I pass these headers in my test case using GraphQlTester?
What I've Tried:

I looked into the GraphQlTester documentation but couldn't find a way to set headers.
I searched online for examples but didn't find a solution that works with GraphQlTester.

Any help on how to pass headers in the test case would be greatly appreciated!

You should show the controller's code.

You can inject in your test an HttpGraphQlTester instance and then configure default HTTP headers on it for your test:
HttpGraphQlTester tenantTester = graphQlTester.mutate()
            .webTestClient((client) -> client.defaultHeaders((headers) -> headers.set("TENANT-CODE", "1234")))
            .build();

